# Styling a disabled RadListView swipe action

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

It appears that if a RadListView swipe action is disabled then it simply disappears from the swipe actions list, although the action's space is still consumed.  It's as if both the color and backgroundColor properties were set to white.

Is there a way to control this?  I tried several :disabled css options but none seem to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this underscores why it's useful to post the code in question - my bad.  I noticed I had spelled the css color "grey" instead of "gray".  Now the styling is being applied as expected.